# How to keep header when the soft keyboard comes in with full screen?

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-fullscreen

I have a header on a chat that move up every time you click on EditText, and disappear,

To fix this problem, I added on Oncreate this

`getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

that works perfect, but when I add this one UIt doesnt work

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

That line make the activity full screen, I tryed to add in the manifest instead but It doesnt work, It sound like if you use one, you cant use the other...

Any ideas how to solve this?

P.D: I tested with adjustPan, and some many things...

Comment: How much screen portion does your App takes without the FullScreen Flags and why ?

Comment: Without the FullScreen Flags it take all the screen except the "Top" bar (Where you see notifications and hour) but i want to have it full

Answer (score 0):

Please Edit your `Manifest.xml` file and add this to your Chat Activity's Tag:

```
<activity
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
 ...
</activity>
```

By using this, you will not need to use `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`
 and this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thx for the reply, unfortunately this doesnt work, I tryed everything in the manifest and it doesnt solve the problem plus it give me a black background